# TypeScript Compiler API: Get resolved return type of a generic method

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

Supposing we have a generic class or an interface:

```js
interface A<T> {
    prop1: T;
    func2(): T;
}

interface B extends A<C> {
}


interface C {
}
```

We need to get the return type of the `B.func2` method (not `T` but `C`).

The way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944135/typescript-compiler-api-how-to-get-type-with-resolved-type-arguments) works OK for props, but I can't figure out how to modify it for methods:

```js
for (const statement of sourceFile.statements) {

    if (!isInterface(statement))
        continue;

    if (!statement.heritageClauses?.length)
        continue;

    for (const heritageClause of statement.heritageClauses) {

        for (const exprWithTypeArgs of heritageClause.types) {
            const baseType = checker.getTypeAtLocation(exprWithTypeArgs);

            for (const propSymbol of baseType.getProperties()) {
                const resolvedType = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(propSymbol, exprWithTypeArgs);

                console.log(`${propSymbol.name} has type: ${resolvedType.symbol?.name}`);
                // prints
                // prop1 has type: C
                // func2 has type: func1

                for (const propDeclaration of propSymbol.declarations) {
                    if (!isSignatureDeclaration(propDeclaration))
                        continue;

                    const signature = checker.getSignatureFromDeclaration(propDeclaration);
                    const returnTypeSymbol = checker.getReturnTypeOfSignature(signature)?.symbol;
                    const resolvedReturnType = checker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(returnTypeSymbol, exprWithTypeArgs);

                    console.log(`${propSymbol.name} return type: ${resolvedReturnType.symbol?.name}`);
                    // prints
                    // func2 return type: undefined
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of getting resolved return type of a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TypeChecker#getSignaturesOfType` method allows for getting the signature of a type.

```
const bDecl = sourceFile.statements[1]; // obviously, improve this
const bType = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(bDecl);
const func2Symbol = bType.getProperty("func2")!;
const func2Type = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(func2Symbol, func2Symbol.valueDeclaration);
const func2Signature = checker.getSignaturesOfType(func2Type, ts.SignatureKind.Call)[0];

checker.typeToString(func2Signature.getReturnType()); // C
```