# How to get a array's resolved type argument (tsc compiler API)

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I've already seen [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944135/typescript-compiler-api-how-to-get-type-with-resolved-type-arguments), but although the name is similar, the question is really a different one, because they're trying to get the type of a property, which happens to be the same as the generic type argument, but I'm trying to get the actual resolved type argument, because I want to get the type `T` of `Array<T>`, and there's no property of type `T` inside the array type.

So I have a function like this:

```
import ts from 'typescript'

function convertType(tc: ts.TypeChecker, type: ts.Type) {
    if (type.symbol.name === 'Array') {
        debugger;
        // How do I get the resolved type of T?
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
}
```

I've noticed that if I debug the function and hover over `type`, it'll have a property called `resolvedTypeArguments` which has the exact type I need. So I could just do `(type as any).resolvedTypeArguments`, but that'd be a hack and I wonder if there's an official way to do it.

I was guessing I'd have to use one of the `is...` functions to cast the type into something that has a `resolvedTypeArguments` property, but there's no mention of "resolvedTypeArguments" anywhere in the whole "typescript.d.ts" file, so it seems that I'm not supposed to access that member at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the type of the first type parameter:

```
const params = checker.getTypeArguments(type);
console.log(checker.typeToString(params[0])); // T
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but I can't pass `type` to `getTypeArguments` because the function takes a `TypeReference`. How do I get a `TypeReference` from a `Type`?

Comment: It seems that I can use [tsutil](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsutils) `isTypeReference` to safely cast it.